# Why does my python request retrieve the incorrect xml?

Tags: python, request, lxml

I'm using python requests to parse a web page. The problem I have is that I'm requesting XML for 2 different paths but when I parse the results, they are the same when they should be different:

```
ca_page = requests.get(../ca/..)
en_page = requests.get(../en/..)
```

When I access the page in my browser I can see that the values are different but when I send a request, the values are the same. Any ideas why this is happening?

**Update:**

So turns out requests has the following to prevent redirects

```
page = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
```

The problem with this is that I get the correct url, but it no longer loads the correct html tags

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can make request in different sessions and check e.g:

```
with requests.session() as s1:
    ca_page = s1.get(../ca/..)
    print ca_page
with requests.session() as s2:
    en_page = s2.get(../en/..)
    print en_page
```

If this does not work then check the documentation of the api/url which you are calling.

Comment: Didn't quite work. I'm going to take a further look but when i check the url I requested, it changes ../ca/.. to ../us/..